# Windows 8 installed by WDS will not activate

Tags: windows, wds, reinstall

I would like to stop using the preload from the manufactures (HP, Acer, etc) and perform a clean install on all the new notebooks before we sell them. But there is one major problem:

When I reinstall Windows 8 with WDS, Windows keeps saying that the used product key is invalid.

As far as I can remember, Windows 8 should read the product key from the BIOS; but I think there's a glitch there.

However, when I reinstall them with an OEM DVD they activate without any problem.

Here's the catch: I used the `boot.wim` and the `install.wim` from the OEM DVD and loaded them into WDS, but they won't activate.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? This problem has been bugging me for weeks now.

Comment: Off the top of my head, it's probably something in the unattend answer file that happens during the Generalize phase.

Answer (score 2):

Last time I checked, WDS wasn't supported with OEM media. It requires a MAK or KMS activation from a volume license.

Comment: you may have a point there.
i think i'll have to aks my question on a different way.

Is there a way to reinstall new laptops with WDS ? 
Not windows8 PRO/Enterprise just Windows8. Some People advice to uninstall the 
additional software but that's no option, the Operating system 
isn't clean anymore if we do so. 

Kind regards.

Comment: I found a solution for my problem.
it't a little bit dirty but it works.

i clean installed with the DVD ( where windows activates without problems) and then syspreped the machine and uploaded it to the server. then i did an install with wds with the image i took based on the DVD install and guess what ?  . . . it works.

Answer (score -1):

I came across the same glitch too. Just use the program `rweverything` and look at the MSDM tab. The key is shown there.